# SharedPreferences java.lang.ClassCastException on Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Today I have found an error just on Samsung Galaxy Tab A 10.1 about `SharedPreferences`

I am saving a Long doing :

```
    private static final String PREF_IDE_CULTIVO_WORK_REPORT = "ID_CULTIVO_WORK_REPORT";
    private static final String PREFNAME = "PREFERENCES";

 public static void init(Context context){
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFNAME, 0);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }
     public static Long getIdCultivoWorkReport(){
            if (sharedPreferences == null){
                return null;
            }
            return sharedPreferences.getLong(PREF_IDE_CULTIVO_WORK_REPORT, 0);
        }
        public static void setIdCultivoWorkReport(Long b){
            if (sharedPreferences == null){
                return;
            }
            editor.putLong(PREF_IDE_CULTIVO_WORK_REPORT, b);
            editor.commit();
        }
```

In one class I set a value;

```
 PreferenceManager.setIdCultivoWorkReport(Long.valueOf(document.getPlantation().getId()));
```

In other class I get the value:

```
       if (PreferenceManager.getIdCultivoWorkReport() == 0 || PreferenceManager.getIdCultivoWorkReport() == null ) {
            allParcelList.addAll(WorkReportController.getParcelsByPlantation(plantationId));
            allSowingList.addAll(WorkReportController.getSowingsByPlantation(plantationId));
        } else{
//get other values
}
```

On an Galaxy Tab A I get a crash on other tablet models works fine

> java.lang.ClassCastException:    at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong
>   (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:249)   at
>   es.app.company.utils.PreferenceManager.getIdCultivoWorkReport
>   (PreferenceManager.java:294)   at
>   es.app.company.ui.workreport.WorkReportEditTaskFragment.onActivityCreated
>   (WorkReportEditTaskFragment.java:130)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated
>   (Fragment.java:1970)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
>   (FragmentManager.java:1041)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
>   (FragmentManager.java:1197)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run (BackStackRecord.java:738) 
>   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions
>   (FragmentManager.java:1562)   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run
>   (FragmentManager.java:483)   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
>   (Handler.java:739)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:95)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7303)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1230)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1120

What I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you change the type of an entry in your code (i.e. if a previous version of the app used `editor.putString(PREF_IDE_CULTIVO_WORK_REPORT, "1");`)

you can solve this if you implement you own local `getLong()` with a `try catch` block.

If you uninstall and then install the app again the local file that contains the data for sharedPreferences will be deleted and the problem on the tab should be gone.